# How to add Google Map Container to GUI builder on Codename One?

Tags: java, google-maps, user-interface, mobile, codenameone

I am trying to build an app using the Codename One GUI builder (which has been fantastic so far). I need to add a Google Maps container to my GUI but I am unsure as to how to do it either in the builder itself or by subclassing. Any examples or links to examples are more than welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether this is referring to the old or new GUI builder. Either way neither one supports the `MapContainer` our of the box as it is an extension and not a builtin component. This might change with the new GUI builder

For both GUI builders just create a border layout form. In the old GUI builder add the `MapContainer` in the "before" callback event. In the new GUI builder add it right after the init call. Make sure to use the `BorderLayout.CENTER` constraint.

Comment: In which .java file do I do this? Because you are not supposed to edit the generated class so does this mean you subclassed?

Comment: userclasses/StateMachine.java

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the old GUI builder based on this... As David said you need to use the before* callback which is in the statemachine (not the statemachine base) see this: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html